# ¿Por qué me sale la gráfica en blanco?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="slide-text slide_style_left">
                    <h1 data-animation="animated zoomInRight">IT</h1>
                    <p data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">Faismon</p>

                    <?php include '/../Tablas/tabla1.php';?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">            
        <div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>
        <h1 data-animation="animated zoomInRight">IT</h1>
        <p data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">Faismon</p>

        <?php  include '/1graf.php';?>             
    </div> 
</div>
```

Sucede que la gráfica me la muestra en blanco totalmente y ya no se que me falta. Cuando la llamo aparte me sale normal, y ya elimine grandes partes del código del carrusel pensando que podría ser eso pero tampoco, sigue saliendo en blanco.

No sé qué mas agregar o donde más ponerle cosas para que me salga lo que necesito. Esta sería la gráfica:

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 120,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 20,
                beta: 35,
                depth: 70
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grafica gestion'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Gestion Comercial'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 60
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
            <?php
             $sql=mysql_query("select * from indica where proce = '1' order by proce desc");
             while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){            
             ?>                  

            ['<?php echo $res['fdi']; ?>'],
             <?php
             }
             ?>
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Valores',
            data: [

            <?php
             $sql=mysql_query("select * from indica where proce = '1' order by proce desc");
             while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){            
             ?>          

            [<?php echo $res['resulsum'] ?>],

             <?php
             }
             ?>
            ]
        }]
    });
});
        </script>
```

Obviamente tiene script de estilos y todo eso, pero por alguna razón no me deja ponerlos acá. Pero, como decía, esta gráfica cuando la llamo usando la URL `http://192.168.0.55:888/trew/graficos/1graf.php`, me la trae normal toda bonita  jajjaja, pero de la otra manera nada.

Comment: Hola Shushin, bienvenido! Sería más sencillo ayudarte si incluyes en la pregunta el código php de los includes (valga la redundancia). ¿Cómo generas la gráfica? Se genera completamente en el php de 1graf.php o interviene algo de javaScript? En el último caso, sería bueno que lo incluyas también. Un saludo!

Comment: También si intengas debugar la página para que muestre si hay algún error php, y/o revisar el log en busca de errores, podría facilitar que se localice el problema :-)

Comment: mira hay puse la grafica de esas mismas son 67 mas pero ps primero quiero que el carousel me traiga al menos 1 pero nada y para llamarlo si solo uso ese incluide pero digamos si la hoja esta en blanco bien pero cuando traigo el codigo de carousel hay es donde las cosas se complican

Comment: Genial Shushin. Lo que has incluido es el contenido de 1graf.php, correcto? :-) Entiendo que estás utilizando el plugin highcharts? ¿podrías incluir el resultado que se imprime para categories y data a partir de las consultas?

Comment: el resultado lo trae directo de la  base de datos puesto que proviene de un formulario toda la información

Comment: Válido, pero para efectos de ayudar a hacer debug, es importante validar que highcharts esté recibiendo lo que crees que recibe